# Need specific chaincode for PDC(Private Data Collection)?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I am trying using PDC on hyperledger fabric for testing.

So then, I heard that PDC needs specific chaincode for itself, not exactly.

For using PDC, do it need something special chaincode only for PDC??

Comment: This is more of a how-to question; the Hyperledger Fabric documentation contains the information about how to set up and use private data collections

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to make `colletions_config.yaml` file.

When you instantiate the chaincode, specify the flag `--collections-config [path]`

Chaincode Functions:

- `stub.GetPrivateData()`
- `stub.PutPrivateData()`

See this page

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private_data_tutorial.html